# Retrieving emails with Web scraping using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to retrieve all notary emails from the area of Barcelona which are publicly available at https://www.notariado.org/portal/. First, I enter "Barcelona" into the location field and then I try to retrieve each email which come in buckets of 5 per page (to that effect, there's buttons which I understand need to be clicked to access the email address). However, I get the following exception. Any help will be much appreciated:

---

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0b5fc155bd68> in <module>
     69 
     70         time.sleep(1)
---> 71         button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="heading{}"]/div/h4/span').format(i)
     72         button.click()
     73         time.sleep(1)
```

---

I'm copy pasting the code I have up to now:

```
import re
import re
import requests
import urllib
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urljoin, urlencode
from collections import deque
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
import google
from googlesearch import search
import time
from random import randint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Safari()
items = range(0,26,1)

emails_notarios = list()

next_url = "https://www.notariado.org/portal/"
driver.get(next_url)
response = requests.get(next_url)

barcode = "Barcelona"
element_enter = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="valor4"]')
element_enter.clear()
element_enter.send_keys(barcode)
time.sleep(1)

button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="portlet_com_liferay_journal_content_web_portlet_JournalContentPortlet_INSTANCE_nWpBPvnHOnbm"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button')
button.click()
time.sleep(1)

for item in items:
    
    base_url = "https://www.notariado.org/portal/Elige%20a%20tu%20notario%20orden?Nombre=&Apellidos=&CodigoPostal=&Poblacion=Barcelona"
    
    if item == 0:
        next_url = base_url
    
    elif item == 1:
        continue
    
    else:
        int_url = base_url + "#result-page-" + "{}"
        next_url = int_url.format(item)
    
    for i in range(0,6,1):
    
        time.sleep(1)
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="heading{}"]/div/h4/span').format(i)
        button.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        
        try:

            response = requests.get(next_url)
            new_emails_2 = set(re.findall(r'\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]{3,}\.[A-Z0-9.-]{2,4}\b', response.text, re.I))
            print(new_emails_2)
            emails_notarios.append(new_emails_2)
        except:
            continue
    
    print(emails_notarios)
    
    time.sleep(1)
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="jwpg_pagination"]/ul/li[{}]/a').format(item+2)
    button.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **NoSuchElementException** means that the Element that you are looking for, in this case `[@id="heading{}"]/div/h4/span` is not there. That means that there is a Problem with your Xpath Selector.

Comment: Thanks @Woopus123, yes I know it is a problem with the element lookup however I can't figure out why the element is not there

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking it a bit too much.

If you select "inspect" with the right-click button, you can get the HTML of the page and see how the data is structured.

First, if I am to set a point of start for recollecting several entries, I like to select the WebElement that gathers all information related to each entry. In this case, you can see that each slot has a root WebElement

- **div[@id = "AccordionPR"][@class = "x"]**, being **x** an iterator starting from 1.

Starting from there, if you go through the children of each one, you will find that there is one WebElement that gathers the information it is displayed when accessing the webpage

- **div[@class = "card-header"][@id = "heading0"]**

And another one that covers the information collapsed for that WebElement

- **div[@class = "collapse"][@id = "collapseP0"]**

Which you can use as an XPath without needing to click in boxes/buttons and adding extra lines to your code.

Also, if you check the HTML code with "Inspect", you can see that the root WebElement I have described before gathers 123 different entries, so you don't really need to do the loops operations of range(0,6,1), as you can access all element at the same time.

Regarding the problem, I would suggest trying another XPath element like this one:

```
entries = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id = "AccordionPR"]") #Selecting all the 123 entries
for entry in entries:
    email = entry.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div[@class = "collapse"]//div[@class = 'col-12']/b[text() = 'Correo electrónico:']") #Finding the location
    email = email.find_element(By.XPATH, "./../a").text  #'..' is used to go back to the parent node
    print(email)
```

Comment: Thank you @JorgeHB, I appreciate your guidance, however, I can't make it work with your suggestions